# Cannot play any video on epiphany

Tags: video, gnome, flash, totem, epiphany

I have installed the **EPIPHANY WEB BROWSER** developed by *GNOME*

But the problem i face is i cannot see any video on it..!!

No flash content is displayed either.

Only a window showing **TOTEM** player shows up...How can i get it working??

I have Flashplayer plugin installed along with Gnash.

Only some YOUTUBE videos can be played.But only a handfull of them..!!

here is what happens-

1.**FLASH CONTENT**

[image: flash]

2.**YOUTUBE VIDEO**

[image: youtube]

Videos from no other sites can be seen

---

@Subv3rsion

It gave me the following error-

[image: hhg]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the totem browser plugin:

```
sudo apt-get purge totem-mozilla
```

And you should try to install Flash Player from Software Center (or try installing `flashplugin-installer`)

Comment: I deleted the totem plugin and my flashplugin is already in the newest version. now after removing the totem plugin, a **missing plugin** symball is shown. NOw what to do??

Comment: On which site do you get that error? It could be a site that requires Microsoft Silverlight, but if it's definitely because of flash, try to reinstall it.

Comment: But the videos play on linux from chrome..!! its only a problem in epiphany..!!

Comment: I think Chrome has its own Flash Player that's perhaps installed through Chrome instead of Software Center. Try Firefox. Does it work there?

Comment: well its working fine with mozella too..!!! I dont know why it isnt with *Epiphany* :( Its a gr8 light weight browser for browsering the net..!! :(

Comment: Then, if you don't have much Settings and bookmarks, try to remove epiphany and flash completely, because it should use the same plugins as firefox (as Subv3rsion mentioned in his answer) with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge flashplugin-installer epiphany-browser` and then install them again with `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer epiphany-browser`

Answer (score 1):

Installing gstreamer can help. It is working for me, running Ubuntu 20.04.

`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio`

Further reference: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c#

Comment: hi, the question is about a missing package, your answer isn't addressing the question. the package mentioned is not in the repositories. Possibly the restricted repositories have to be enabled, or the repositories need to be updated by running 'apt-get update'.

Comment: hi, the reply answers the question subject....

Answer (score 0):

Do you installed flashplugin-nonfree if not, run:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

EPIPHANY or Firefox, run the same flash plugin in the same location.

---

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

found [this](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Epiphany#Flash) on the Arch wiki for epiphany.